# how to calculate time difference between non-consecutive rows based on condition from another row in R?

Tags: r

```
time <- c('2020-04-25 00:00:12', '2020-04-25 00:01:20', '2020-04-25 00:02:40', 
          '2020-04-25 00:02:48', '2020-04-25 00:02:58', '2020-04-25 00:03:15',
          '2020-04-25 00:03:45', '2020-04-25 00:04:23', '2020-04-25 00:04:45', 
          '2020-04-25 00:05:18', '2020-04-25 00:05:36', '2020-04-25 00:05:55')

id <- c('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1')

status <- c("idle", "idle", "idle", "idle", "off", "off", "idle", "idle", "use", "use", "use", "idle" )

df <-data.frame(id, time, status)

df
   id                time status
1   1 2020-04-25 00:00:12   idle
2   1 2020-04-25 00:01:20   idle
3   1 2020-04-25 00:02:40   idle
4   1 2020-04-25 00:02:48   idle
5   1 2020-04-25 00:02:58    off
6   1 2020-04-25 00:03:15    off
7   1 2020-04-25 00:03:45   idle
8   1 2020-04-25 00:04:23   idle
9   1 2020-04-25 00:04:45    use
10  1 2020-04-25 00:05:18    use
11  1 2020-04-25 00:05:36    use
12  1 2020-04-25 00:05:55   idle
```

hi, 
i have the dataset above and i would like to calculate the time difference for each block of status. how would you do it? i.e i would want to know the time difference between the first "idle" to the last "idle" in the first block and so on. 
in other words, what i would want is time difference between idle[4]-idle[1], idle[8]-idle[7] etc.

is there a way to do it in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create groups for every block and calculate the difference in time between `last` and `first` `time` in seconds.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time, tz = "UTC"), 
         grp = cumsum(status != 'idle')) %>%
  filter(status == 'idle') %>%
  group_by(id, grp) %>%
  summarise(diff = difftime(last(time), first(time), units = "secs")) %>%
  select(-grp)

#  id    diff    
#  <chr> <drtn>  
#1 1     156 secs
#2 1      38 secs
```

Comment: @chinsoon12: may i know how did u type the question into the current format as compared to when i posted it? thanks!

Comment: I guess it is just print `df` in console, copy and paste in your question.